# Using qsub parameters in PBS script options

Tags: environment-variables, pbs, qsub, torque

I want to use parameters I've passed in to a PBS script in the PBS `-N` option. For example, when I run the PBS script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N job_${num}

echo ${num}
```

with

```
qsub -v num=0 script.sh
```

It will start a job where the name is `job_0`.

With the above, a job with the name `job_{num}`. When I try using the line `#PBS -N job_$num`, I receive an error that the output files were not able to be created.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that lines within a job script such as

```
#PBS -N job_${num}
```

aren't resolved by the command line. The way to do what you're trying to do would be something like:

`num=0; qsub -v num=$num -Njob_${num} script.sh`

Where script.sh contains:

`#!/bin/bash
echo ${num}`